# Extracting a part from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string like this `LatLng(41.3371, 19.81717)`stored in variable `a`
But I only need the number `41.3371` to make some further calculation.
Any idea on how I can extract the number?

Comment: Why is it a string in the first place?

Comment: try reading _any_ introductory book to Java, first..?

Comment: @Alnitak why - so he can then become a Java programmer, earn some money, and buy a JavaScript book? ;)

Comment: JavaScript documentation is your friend. There are plenty of [`String` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML) that will help you do this.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions you can do `/^LatLng\((\d+\.\d+), (\d+\.\d+)\)$/`.

**With javascript:**

```
console.log('LatLng(41.3371, 19.81717)'.match(/^LatLng\((\d+\.\d+), (\d+\.\d+)\)$/)[1]);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression like

```
<div id="res"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var res = document.getElementById('res'),
        re = /\((\d+\.\d+),\s*(\d+\.\d+)\)/,
        str = 'LatLng(41.3371, 19.81717)',
        m = str.match(re);
    res.innerHTML = 'x = ' + m[1] + ' and y = ' + m[2];
</script>
```

​

​
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/ZZbV7/)

Comment: I am using the code above but instead of str = 'LatLng(41.3371, 19.81717)',  I have to put str = a, where "a" is the variable containing the LatLng(41.3371, 19.81717) value. "a" is being assigned the value LatLng(41.3371, 19.81717) in a function inside the script.

Comment: So your `a` variable and `str` variable are not strings, but an instance of LatLng? If yes, which value provides a.toString()? Is there a methods or properties to get a latitude and longitude directly from object?

Comment: Thanks Evgeiny. Eventually, I used another geolocation function to extract only the coordinate values.